# Using cellcontentclick event in a c# program that activates a link

Tags: c#, datagridview, hyperlink

I have a program that uses a datagridview with 7 columns in it. One of the columns is a hyperlink that will load a file from a specified location.  I use a 'cellcontentclick' event to open the file.  My problem is, when I click any of the other cells in the row, it will still execute the cellcontentclick.  How do I make it so only when that specific column will execute when clicked?

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string sourcePath = @"SPECIFIED PATH";

            Process.Start(sourcePath + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inside event handler only for column you are looking for.
One of the parameters (e?) has column info.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I just needed to enter the if statement and specify the column. Thanks, evgenyl.

```
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string sourcePath = @"PATH";

                Process.Start(sourcePath + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);
            }

            catch (SqlException a)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + a);
            }
        }
```